# From Database Sqlite to AngularJS HTML

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, razor

I trying to convert HTML code from database to my page.

```
@foreach (DataRow Row in DT.Rows)
{
    <p>@Row.ItemArray[1]</p>
    <span ng-bind-html="mydata"></span>
    <hr />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('magnos', ['ngSanitize']);
        app.controller('mycont', function ($scope) {
            $scope.mydata = '@Row.ItemArray[2]';
        });
        
    </script>
}
```

But `the @Row.ItemArray[2]` is always return string, not HTML like this
`<h1>Magnos</h1>`

I want the HTML code to write as HTML code in my page, so the Magnos header show as header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all I have found the solution,
Heres the Solution:-

```
@foreach (DataRow Row in DT.Rows)
{
    <h2>@Row.ItemArray[1]</h2>
    <br />
    <span ng-bind-html="get_pre('@Row.ItemArray[2]');"></span>
    <hr />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('magnos', []);
        app.controller('mycont', function ($scope, $sce) {
        
            $scope.get_pre = function (x) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(x);
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).